# dd is writing indefinitely until disk is full

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, dd

I want to **dd** my microSD card, 32 GB, on which I installed RasberryPiOS.

I plugged my 2TB SSD with 150GB space left, and send the following command:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/media/pi/Samsung_T5/raspi2.sda1.img
```

But the process stops when raspi2.sda1.img is 149 GB.

How can it be? Since my microSD card is only 32GB, with 25GB free space left?

I also tried the following, overnight:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda1 | gzip -c >/media/pi/Samsung_T5/raspi2.sda1.img.gz
```

And this morning it was 70GB already!!

Also, I determined the partition name using **parted**, if that can be of any help to answer the question.

Thanks.

Comment: "_I want to `dd` my microSD card_" no you don't. You should just use `cat`. For example `cat /dev/sda1 >/media/pi/Samsung_T5/raspi2.sda1.img`. But if you're currently using the system that you're trying to copy you will quite possibly end up with an invisibly corrupted image. `dd` or `cat` - it's entirely the wrong solution

Comment: What's the output of `lsblk`, `bockdev --getsize64 /dev/sda /dev/sda1`, `grep sda /proc/partitions`?

Comment: @roaima : you're right, I don't know what "wanting to dd an sdcard" really means. I just found this: https://linoxide.com/linux-dd-command-create-1gb-file/ where I wanted to learn how to create an img of my rpi that I could load in my VM manager. What is cat doing?

Comment: That's a better question, "how can I clone my SD card? Here's what I've tried...". You should then get answers that explain how to do it correctly and safely. Most of the examples in that linked document could be trivially replaced more efficiently with `cat`